# undefined method `reviews' for #<Post:0x007fa207cb7c70>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following a tutorial on how to implement reviews for my rails app, users can add reviews for posts. But when i click add new review i get 'NoMethodError in Reviews#new'

Reviews controller

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post

 def new
  @review = Review.new
end


def create
  @review = Review.new(review_params)

  @review.post_id = @post.id
  @review.user_id = current_user.id

  if @review.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
  render 'New'
  end

end

private

def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)

end

def find_post
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])

end

end
```

Review model

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  belongs_to :user
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  validates_presence_of :title , :description

end
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot `has_many :reviews` in your `Post` model. (Also, please don't post pictures of code. It makes it impossible to copy/paste. And, it can be difficult to view pictures on smaller devices.)

Comment: wow can't believe i missed that, it worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot `has_many :reviews` in your `Post` model.